# "Can't allocate region" malloc error when running millions of iterations of loop

Tags: objective-c, malloc, nsdictionary, instruments

Thanks to a lot of help I've received here on SO, I've gotten an algorithm to check a list of around 15,000 8-letter words for any partial anagrams, against a list of around 50,000 total words (so I suppose a total of 108 million iterations). I call this method once for each comparison (so 750 million times). I'm getting the following error, always somewhere in the midst of the 119th iteration through the 1,350 there should be:

```
AnagramFINAL(2960,0xac8c7a28) malloc: *** mmap(size=2097152) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I've narrowed the memory issue down to being a huge number of allocated CFStrings (immutable). Any idea what I can do to remedy the issue? I'm using ARC and an `@autoreleasepool`, not sure what else I could do, it seems something isn't being released when it should be.

AnagramDetector.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AnagramDetector : NSObject {

        NSDictionary *allEightLetterWords;
NSDictionary *allWords;

    NSFileManager *fileManager;
    NSArray *paths;
    NSString *documentsDirectory;
    NSString *filePath;
}

- (BOOL) does: (NSString *) longWord contain: (NSString *) shortWord;
- (NSDictionary *) setupAllWordList;
- (NSDictionary *) setupEightLetterWordList;
- (void) saveDictionary: (NSMutableDictionary *)currentArray;

@end
```

AnagramDetector.m

```
@implementation AnagramDetector

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL) does: (NSString *) longWord contain: (NSString *) shortWord {
    @autoreleasepool {
          NSMutableString *longerWord = [longWord mutableCopy];
          for (int i = 0; i < [shortWord length]; i++) {
              NSString *letter = [shortWord substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
              NSRange letterRange = [longerWord rangeOfString: letter];
              if (letterRange.location != NSNotFound) {
                  [longerWord deleteCharactersInRange: letterRange];
              } else {
                  return NO;
              }
          }
        return YES;
    }
}

- (NSDictionary *) setupAllWordList {

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *fileWithAllWords = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AllDefinedWords" ofType:@"plist"];
        allWords = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: fileWithAllWords];
        NSLog(@"Total number of words: %d.", [allWords count]);
    }
    return allWords;
}


- (NSDictionary *) setupEightLetterWordList {

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *fileWithEightWords = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AllDefinedEights" ofType:@"plist"];
        allEightLetterWords = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: fileWithEightWords];
        NSLog(@"Total number of words: %d.", [allEightLetterWords count]);
    }
    return allEightLetterWords;
}

- (void) saveDictionary: (NSMutableDictionary *)currentArray {

    @autoreleasepool {
        filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"A.plist"];
        [fileManager createFileAtPath:filePath contents: nil attributes: nil];
        [currentArray writeToFile: filePath atomically:YES];
        [currentArray removeAllObjects];
    }
}

@end
```

Code running on launch (inside AppDelegate for now, since no VC):

```
@autoreleasepool {

    AnagramDetector *detector = [[AnagramDetector alloc] init];

    NSDictionary *allWords   = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[detector setupAllWordList]];
    NSDictionary *eightWords = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[detector setupEightLetterWordList]];

    int remaining = [eightWords count];

    for (NSString *currentEightWord in eightWords) {
        if (remaining % 10 == 0) NSLog(@"%d ::: REMAINING :::", remaining);
        for (NSString *currentAllWord in allWords) {
            if ([detector does: [eightWords objectForKey: currentEightWord] contain: [allWords objectForKey: currentAllWord]]) {
                // NSLog(@"%@ ::: CONTAINS ::: %@", [eightWords objectForKey: currentEightWord], [allWords objectForKey: currentAllWord]);
            }
        }
        remaining--;
    }
}
```

[image: Instruments]

Comment: How does the memory graph look? sawtooth or linear up + sawtooth? maybe one call to `does:contains:` creates too many objects as the autoreleased objects are not released until the method returns.

Comment: No sawtooth, just a straight line. Shoots up almost immediately and stays there until the crash.

Comment: Ok and it does several calls to that method before crashing? do you have a `@autoreleasepool` in the method calling `does:contains:` too? would be great the see the whole code.

Comment: would be great to see the whole code*

Comment: I do, yes. I'll add the whole code above now.

Comment: I don't have word lists to test with but if i use dummy lists (key1: value1, ...) the memory increases at start and then stabilise. I can only spot one place where you might create a autoreleased object now: `[shortWord substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(i, 1)]`.

Comment: A simple clean worked for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be that a lot of autoreleased objects fill up the memory waiting to be released. So a solution is to add your own autorelease pool scope to collect autoreleased objects and release them sooner.

I suggest that you do something like this:

```
for (NSString *currentEightLetterWord in [eightLetterWordsDictionary allKeys]) {
    @autoreleasepool { 
        for (NSString *currentWord in [allWordsDictionary allKeys]) {
        }
    }
}
```

Now all autoreleased objects inside `@autoreleasepool { .. }` will be released for each iteration of the outer loop.

As you see ARC might save you from thinking about most reference counting and memory management issues but objects can still end up in autorelease pools with ARC when using methods that directly or indirectly create autoreleased objects.

An alternative solution that I don't really recommend is to try to avoid using method that will use autorelease. Then `does:contain:` could awkwardly be rewritten to something like this:

```
- (BOOL) does: (NSString* ) longWord contain: (NSString *) shortWord {
    NSMutableString *haystack = [longWord mutableCopy];
    NSMutableString *needle = [shortWord mutableCopy];
    while([haystack length] > 0 && [needle length] > 0) {
        NSMutableCharacterSet *set = [[NSMutableCharacterSet alloc] init];
        [set addCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([needle characterAtIndex:0], 1)];
        if ([haystack rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location == NSNotFound) return NO;
        haystack = [haystack mutableCopy];
        [haystack deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [haystack rangeOfCharacterFromSet: set].location)];
        needle = [needle mutableCopy];
        [needle deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Made no difference at all, still crashes on the 119th iteration unfortunately. Any more ideas?

Comment: Did some tests and i think the problem is still autoreleased objects. Check the updated answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: I did what you suggested, and it gets much further, to around 1043 iterations out of 1350 (rather than 119 like before), but it's still crashing every time at that same point. A lovely non-descript `EXC_??? (11) (code=0, subcode=0x0)` error, too.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I did what you suggested with @autorelease. With the revised method you suggested, it got to around the 800th iteration.

Comment: Do you have `[currentWordAnagrams removeAllObjects]` inside the `@ autoreleasepool` scope? test that if not as im not sure if it will autorelease removed objects or not.

Comment: Also can you log how many objects you have in `anagramArray` and `currentWordAnagrams`? (`NSLog(@"%d", [currentWordAnagrams count]);` ...).

Comment: And as i said i don't really recommend my revised method version as it is harder to understand. I would first try to solve this using only own autoreleasepools.

Comment: I've used various autoreleasepools in various places, and unfortunately I'm still seeing crashes before it finishes all 1350 runs. `currentWordAnagrams` varies for each run of the loop, between 1 and around 5000. `anagramArray` begins with zero, will go to 1350 if all loops iterate properly.

Comment: Ok but note that in each iteration you set `currentWordAnagrams` to a key in `anagramArray` and by doing so you keep the strings referenced and alive.

Comment: So let's do some math to figure out amount of memory needed. Assume `currentWordAnagrams` average on 2500 words and word is around 40 bytes in memory (8 unicode letters plus some object overhead): 2500*1350*40 = 135000000 = ~135MB. Im not sure about my estimate but i would not be surprised if your currently solution is just not memory efficient enough.

Comment: This is running on the sim, and will never need to run on a device – it's a one-time process to build these anagram plists, then I can just use them in the app itself. It's why I'm doing it now, to avoid needing to do it later. 135mb for the entire thing should be fine on my iMac, shouldn't it?

Comment: Also, I've actually removed the call that sets `anagramArray`, I'm writing a separate .plist for each iteration of the for loop. I would've thought that would clear the entire thing out after it writes each file. Is it worth turning ARC off and trying to handle the memory management manually at this point?

Comment: Ah ok, yeah then it should work i guess. But 135 is a very humble estimate and you could end up fragmenting the memory allocator too. If you try without ARC you will still need to avoid autorelease or use autoreleasepools to not get the same result. Are you that the plist write stuff does not leave autoreleased objects that keeps the strings alive somehow?

Comment: It's possible, but unlikely. I've added the saveDictionary method above. Let me know if you think otherwise.

Comment: That looks correct to me. What kinds of objects do you see alive if you use Instruments? also note that in Instruments you can actually see from where each allocated object was allocated, that might help.

Comment: It's mainly CFMutatedStrings.

Comment: Ah your using my method version now and compile without ARC? if so try to use your version instead (as mine will leak without ARC), but change `[longWord copy]` to `[[longWord copy] autorelease]` etc. But in that case i think it is even better to turn on ARC again and use own pools :)

Comment: This is what I gleamed from Instruments over the course of a run, through to the crash:

(CFString Immutable)
Foundation -> _NSParseObjectFromASCIIPropertyListOrSerialization (80457 of these, presumably one per word as expected)
Foundation -> -[NSPlaceholderString initWithBytes:length:encoding:] (82812 of these, one per word and some extras..?)

(CFString Store)
GraphicsServices -> LoadFontPathCache (429 of these, no idea why, no graphics at all in app, 429 has no significance I can see)

(CFString Mutable)
Foundation -> [NSURL(NSURL) path] (1 of these, loading my plists in as expected),

Comment: Do you compile with or without ARC now and do you use autoreleasepools? hard to follow how your code looks right now. I think `NSPlaceholderString` are Objective-C strings constants like `@"bla"`.

Comment: Sorry, I think things might be from different revisions. I'm currently compiling with ARC and @autoreleasepools. I'll take a look over the code in the question tonight and clean it up.

Comment: I've revised the question completely, separated code, tracked down the method that's causing the leak, etc.